# Scrollable text view: shows bottom of text as first

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextview

I've got a little problem: in my app there is a view controller with `UITextView`. The text is too long for one iPhone page, so it is scrollable.  In the simulator, whenever I go to this view, I can only see the lower part of my text. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to top at `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.textView?.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0,length: 0))
}
```

Comment: I was using storyboard to make this view controller with text - where should I put that?

Comment: add the IBOutlet of the textview to view controller's implementation file 

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!